# Adding KO computedobservable to nested object created with KO Mapping (with jsfiddle)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm new to knockout. I have a page that loads some trade data from a wcf call and adds it as a nested ko.observablearray to my view model using ko.mapping.

The loaded trade data has typecode that I need to lookup in a typeCodes array in my viewModel. So i'm trying to use ko.mapping options to create a computed column for each trade added.

http://jsfiddle.net/russellgove/KXneJ/8/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to customize the creation of child objects (add a "create" callback) when calling the mapping plugin.
Here is the modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbos/9ppcv/5).

Comment: I tried to take your changes and incorporate them into my code. I'm really having trouble undertsandining the concept of the create callback. I put debugger statements in the 'create callback, and it doesn't seem to be gettiing called at all.I updated the fidle to better reflect my real code. Could you be so kind to have a look? http://jsfiddle.net/russellgove/RFtDx/21/

Comment: @Russellg you specified `create` for an element in the returned data named `trades` but there is no `trades` element. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/RFtDx/22/

Comment: @Russellg: for the _create_ callback being called, variable _mappings_ should be passed to the function fromJS (2nd parameter). Also 1st parameter should be an object. See updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gbos/RFtDx/23/)

Comment: thanks, I got it.Appreciate all our help. Is this kind of stuff documented anywhere?